# How can I increase the 8 kHz audio sampling rate to 16 kHz STM32

Tags: audio, stm32, adc

Thanks for read my topic

I tried to record the sound, I managed to record the sound at a sample rate of 8 kHz.

this is my code it works great. But I need more sample rate like 11kHz or 16 kHz, I do not know how I can increase my sample rate to this rate.i use STM32F103C8

I got this code in the source https://www.hackster.io/christopher-william-sutjiono/read-audio-amplifier-circuit-output-using-stm-32-d9acb5

```
    void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
 
 
/* USER CODE END 0 */
#define SAMP 8000
 
 
int main(void)
{
 
    int k;
    uint8_t buf[40];
    uint16_t dat[SAMP]; // store ADC value 'SAMP'variable is 8000 1 sec for store audio
 
  HAL_Init();
 
 
  SystemClock_Config();
 
 
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
 
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);
 
 
 
  while (1)
  {
      for(k=0;k<SAMP;k++)
          {
              while((__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim3))<124);
              HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
              HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
              dat[k] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1); //GET ADC Value
          }
 
          // for loop to print sammples to computer screen with 1 msec pause between samples
 
          for (k=0;k<SAMP;k++)
          {
              sprintf((char*)buf,"%d\r\n", dat[k]);
              HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
              HAL_Delay(1);
          }
 
          HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET);
          HAL_Delay(3000);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_Delay(3000);
 
  }
 
}
htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 16-1;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 125-1;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


  [1]: https://www.hackster.io/christopher-william-sutjiono/read-audio-amplifier-circuit-output-using-stm-32-d9acb5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line `while((__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim3))<124);` is defining your sample rate, reducing the magic number from 124 will increase your sample rate.

There's almost certainly a better way to do this, such as a timer triggered DMA or similar.

Comment: Hi
I am trying to use "timer triggered DMA" but do not know how to configure it